# Wordpress – Link to a date-filter element isn't added to the base url and apply filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Page of WordPress site use an on page filter menu which user can click on items to filter posts type below. I have already added in each anchor tag href value.

```html
<ul class="list-inline filter">
        <li class="active">
       <a href="#.*" data-filter="*">All solutions</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
       <a href="#.Metallurgy" data-filter=".Metallurgy">Metallurgy</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-2"> 
       <a href="#.Food" data-filter=".Food">Food industry</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

And here is js code to simulate a click on the appropriate element based on a URL Fragment.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var currentFilter = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    $('.js-filter [data-filter="'+ currentFilter +'"]').trigger('click');
});
```

The deal is when I click on anchor tag it isn't add a href value after base url. For example, I want to have an url "example.com/solutions#.Metallurgy". Click applies filter on data, but url stays as "example.com/solutions".

Moreover, when I change url directly to "example.com/solutions#.Metallurgy" Wordpress redirects me to "example.com/solutions/#.Metallurgy". It brings me to the same page with no filter applied.